# Configuring specific application to use proxy?

Tags: networking, tcp, proxy, fiddler, fiddlercore

Is it possible to force a specific windows application to use a proxy [address:port] so I can direct its traffic through my FiddlerCore app to analyze?

I could set FiddlerCore as the system-wide proxy, but I don't want to capture all traffic, but rather from a specific application.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to change the proxy settings within the application itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A lot of applications allow to manually set a proxy in it's settings/preferences. If the application does not allow so you can only set Fiddler as system wide proxy and filter for the process you want to inspect network traffic on.

Fiddler can filter the traffic based on the application that creates it.

Check the **Filter** tab and use the option **Show only traffic from** to select the process you want to capture.

[image: Show only traffic from]

Comment: ah is there a way to set this within my own FiddlerCore C# application? rather than the frontend Fiddler App

Comment: @Zeller33 If you implement your handler for e.g. OnBeforeresponse the session object should contain the `LocalProcessID` property which you can use for ignoring certain requests/responses.